# Gem will_paginate ignore :include parameter of ActiveRecord find method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, include, will-paginate, rails-activerecord

I tried to optimize my Rails 2 application, to limit the mySQL query numbers.
Here is a simple example, with 3 models :

An Article has many pictures, through a join model ArticlePicture. The "main picture" is the first, respecting the sequence of the pictures.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord:Bast
  has_many :articles_pictures, :order => 'sequence'
  has_many :pictures, :through => :articles_pictures, :order => 'sequence'
  has_one :main_picture, :through => :articles_pictures, :source => :picture, :conditions => ["# {ArticlesPicture.table_name}.sequence = ?", 0]
end
```

An ArticlePicture is the join model between Article and Picture, with a 'sequence' field.

```
class ArticlesPicture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :picture
end
```

A Picture can belongs to many articles.

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles_pictures
  has_many :articles, :through => :articles_picture
end
```

In my controller, I call all the articles, and paginate it :

```
@articles = Article.all.paginate(:per_page => 50)
```

In my view, I list the articles with an "each" calling

```
article.main_picture
```

Obviously, Rails call a "SELECT" for the 50 first pictures, this is not very optimized. So I try to call the articles with

```
@articles = Article.find(:all, :include => :main_picture).paginate(:per_page => 50)
```

But Rails will create a "SELECT" for the entire picture table, i.e.

```
SELECT `articles_pictures`.*
FROM `articles_pictures`
WHERE (`articles_pictures`.article_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,.....)
```

Is there any options I forgot ?

Regards

Pierre

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing, using `all` with `pagination` means `no using pagination`. Using `all` makes `heavy load` on `db`. It will load all data in `memory`. For large data it takes `long time` to load. Sometimes may `crash` with full memory. So we use `pagination` to load `some data at a time` to give user more responsive. So don't use `all`.

```
 @articles = Article.all.paginate(:per_page => 50)
```

Use like this:

```
 @articles = Article.paginate(:per_page => 50)
 @articles = Article.paginate(:per_page => 50, :include => :main_picture)
```

Comment: I wrote 'all' on this page because my real use case call some named scope. Your solution works : Fantastic !

Comment: I can't, I'm a newbie here, I need to do my reputation. The only thing I can do is thank you to this way :)